# E: package net-tools has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apt, package-management, troubleshooting

I am unable to `apt-get install net-tools`; I get the error

> E: Package net-tools has no installation candidate.

Unlike the other similarly named questions, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have not been able to use the networking troubleshooting tools to work. `apt` is still able to list repositories. I have updated, upgraded, rebooted, and repeated after my attempts but nothing has worked.

Error message:

```
~$ ifconfig

Command 'ifconfig' not found but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools

~$ sudo apt install net-tool
[sudo] password for jordan:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package net-tool

~$ apt-cache policy net-tools
net-tools:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1
    Version table:
        1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1 500
            500 http://pg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 3):

The final `s` is missing from your command:

```
sudo apt install net-tool
```

Try

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

instead.